# How to preserve mixed case in GCP logging as currently it shows all lowercase?

Tags: google-cloud-logging

Following is the one example of the issue.

The code written in ruby as following:

```
 DesLogger.instance.info ("Google::Cloud.configure.use_error_reporting: #{Google::Cloud.configure.use_error_reporting}")
```

However the log entry shown in GCP logging is:

```
INFO -- : google::cloud.configure.use_error_reporting: true
```

The reason for this question is that we have based-64 encoded data shown in GCP logs all in lowercase.  As based-64 encoded data is case sensitive,  it cannot be decoded and hence it blocks for further analysis.

Appreciate for any pointers.

Comment: I assume you've configured a logger per these instructions: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/ruby/writing-application-logs, and I assume you're using the standard "Logger" library with an ordinary "Logger" object.  In which case I don't understand why it seems to be writing your log entries in lower case. If you write a mixed case "Info" log entry using the library ... then that's exactly what should be written to the log file!

Comment: Ends up it's nothing wrong with GCP logging.   It's somewhere in the app code level turning all characters into lowercase.   Thanks for sharing your thought here.

Comment: Makes sense.  Thank you for following up :)